# Serverside Events PHP readystate stuck on 0

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently implementing serverside events using the [EventSource (SSE API)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

I tried setting up a simple example from the link above. Now with the example embeded, I'm getting a client wanting to connect and it always stucks in readyState = 0. What could be the cause?

Code:
PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while(true) {
    $time = date('r');
    echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    session_write_close();
    if(connection_aborted()) { break; }

    sleep(1);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource('/pingen/PingenEventHandler.php');
console.log(evtSource.withCredentials);
console.log(evtSource.readyState);
console.log(evtSource.url);

evtSource.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connection to server opened.");
};

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data)
};

evtSource.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log("EventSource failed.");
};
```

As soon as I remove the while loop in the PHP file, it works once and then the connection aborts ofcourse.

Any help appreciated!

**Update:**
Using the following PHP Code I'm able to receive events on the client side but they are not sent one by one but about 20 together. What could be the cause?

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while(true) {
    $data = [
        'name' => 'Rasmus Lerdorf'
    ];

    $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);

    echo "event: sse\n";
    echo "data: This is a message at time " . $curDate . "\n\n";
    echo str_pad('', 4096) . "\n";
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    session_write_close();
    if(connection_aborted()) { break; }

    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: afaik `echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";` won't work in PHP. Need to use `echo "data: The server time is: ".$time."\n\n";` instead.

Comment: @icecub It does. But even with that changed the SSE doesn't work still as described above.

Comment: I noticed It's ending up in a 504 Gateway Timeout Error.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what's going on there. I've never used SSE myself as I prefer to use websockets instead. They're way more convenient imho. Especially since using PHP's `sleep()` function is questionable at best. You're literally just halting the PHP interpreter. Ratchet (socketo.me) websocket library for example has build in ReactPHP support, which allows you to use asynchronous timers within PHP on your server.